# Adding list item from list<> after comparing using c#

Tags: c#, list

I do have List control, in which I am adding items.
I have another generic list of say List for comparing, I want to compare the items of List control, and if I found the match I don't wants to include it in my another list say list.

```
foreach( S s1 in S_list)
{
    if (ex.Count > 0)  // If list not empmty
    {
        foreach(Ex li in ex)  // 
        {
            if (s1.Name.Equals(li.ToString()))
            {
                flag=true;
                ex.Add(s1.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ex.Add(s1.Name);
    }
}
```

Problem is:

Its causing duplication in my ex list, how to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood what are you trying to achieve, but this code looks suspicious to me:

```
foreach(Ex li in ex)  // 
{
    if (s1.Name.Equals(li.ToString()))
    {
        flag=true;
        ex.Add(s1.Name);
    }
}
```

So, you add `s1.Name` to list every time when you find the same element in the list? This way `ex` will be populated with elements equal to the first added element.

Possibly something like this will do the job:

```
foreach( S s1 in S_list)
{
    boolean foundInEx = false;
    foreach(Ex li in ex)  // 
    {
        if (s1.Name.Equals(li.ToString()))
        {
            foundInEx = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!foundInEx) 
    {
        ex.Add(s1.Name); //only executed when there is no such element in ex
    }
}
```

Shorter way using LINQ [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
foreach( S s1 in S_list)
{
    if(ex.Count(li => s1.Name.Equals(li.ToString()))>0) 
    {
        ex.Add(s1.Name); //only executed when there is no such element in ex
    }
}
```

Also you can use LINQ [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) if you want to get unique elements from list:

```
var uniqueNames = S_list.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks!! Especially for the linq statements.